# Ford-Fulkerson for irrational capacities never terminates

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

We know that the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm works for integer capacities but it may loop forever, and this means that it might never terminate for irrational ones. Could you please further justify this claim as why choosing irrational numbers on the directed network and choose flow-augmenting path s.t the algorithm never terminates?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the network. Some small examples where FF does not converge are given in this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759500022O

Comment: @MarkWildon, Thank you. But is there proof or formal justification made about this?

Comment: Of course the paper also proves that these examples work.

Comment: @MishaLavrovm. Thank you.